# Simple .htaccess rewrite rule but doesn't work properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've trying to rewrite one url but something doesn't work as must and I get the massage

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /1/1.html was not found on this server.

This is what I have in .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /view.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

And this is the `href` link for this case

```
href="/'.$row['id'].'/'.$row['name'].'.html"
```

Any idea why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove leading slash in your rule

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /view.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

You need a leading slash in your rules only if you write it directly in `httpd.conf` instead of `.htaccess` files.

You also need it until `Apache 2.4` if i don't make a mistake

Comment: Thank's for the answer. What about the css styling now because it is dissapeared...

Comment: That's because you have created a virtual directory with your rule. All you have to do is using absolute paths for all your html resources. You can also add `<base href="/">` right after `<head>` html tag in all your concerned pages